# OnLoadFinished in fragment causes NullPointerException, unnable to fix or reproduce the crash

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-contentprovider, android-cursoradapter

I have app where by using fragmentManager I manage fragments. One of the fragments list is WikiItemsFragment

My problem is about NullPointerException in OnLoadFinished

```
x.x.fragments.WikiItemsFragment.onLoadFinished (WikiItemsFragment.java:97)
x.x.fragments.WikiItemsFragment.onLoadFinished (WikiItemsFragment.java:33)
```

where line 33 is describing this fragment class, 
and line 97 is describing `adapter.swapCursor(cursor);`

Well I still cannot reproduce problem but I know it happen due crash raports and it happened to me only few times.
I still don't understand what am I doing wrong that my app crashes in OnLoadFinished method/
How could I force to make my fragment crashed? How could I fix it or even reproduce it? I am working on Nexus 4.

```
public class WikiItemsFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

public static String TAG = WikiItemsFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private ListView listView;
private TextView emptyView;
private TextView wikiItemsInfoBar;
private CursorAdapter adapter;
private Uri uri;
private String[] array;


public static WikiItemsFragment getInstance(Uri contentUri, String[] projectionArray) {
    WikiItemsFragment f = new WikiItemsFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("uri", contentUri);
    bundle.putStringArray("array", projectionArray);
    f.setArguments(bundle);
    return f;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wiki_items, null);

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    emptyView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.empty_list);
    emptyView.setTypeface(Core.robotoRegular);
    wikiItemsInfoBar = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wiki_items_info_bar);
    wikiItemsInfoBar.setTypeface(Core.robotoRegular);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    uri = getArguments().getParcelable("uri");
    array = getArguments().getStringArray("array");

    if (uri == WikiItemsOffensiveTable.CONTENT_URI)
        adapter = new WikiItemsOffensiveAdapter(getActivity());
    else if (uri == WikiItemsDefensiveTable.CONTENT_URI)
        adapter = new WikiItemsDefensiveAdapter(getActivity());
    else if (uri == WikiItemsOtherTable.CONTENT_URI)
        adapter = new WikiItemsOtherAdapter(getActivity());
    else if (uri == WikiItemsUsableTable.CONTENT_URI)
        adapter = new WikiItemsUsableAdapter(getActivity());
    else if (uri == WikiItemsSpecialTable.CONTENT_URI)
        adapter = new WikiItemsSpecialAdapter(getActivity());
    else if (uri == WikiItemsArtifactTable.CONTENT_URI)
        adapter = new WikiItemsArtifactAdapter(getActivity());

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, array, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {

    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `CursorAdapter` can use a `null` value for the method `swapCursor`, it must be that onLoadFinished was called before the adapter was set.

Actually it looks like you issued a lot of ifs here:

```
if (uri == WikiItemsOffensiveTable.CONTENT_URI)
    adapter = new WikiItemsOffensiveAdapter(getActivity());
else if (uri == WikiItemsDefensiveTable.CONTENT_URI)
    adapter = new WikiItemsDefensiveAdapter(getActivity());
else if (uri == WikiItemsOtherTable.CONTENT_URI)
    adapter = new WikiItemsOtherAdapter(getActivity());
else if (uri == WikiItemsUsableTable.CONTENT_URI)
    adapter = new WikiItemsUsableAdapter(getActivity());
else if (uri == WikiItemsSpecialTable.CONTENT_URI)
    adapter = new WikiItemsSpecialAdapter(getActivity());
else if (uri == WikiItemsArtifactTable.CONTENT_URI)
    adapter = new WikiItemsArtifactAdapter(getActivity());
```

But what if else? You must be getting another uri (possibly null, if args not set), so create a default adapter or log an error then. like this:

```
if (uri == WikiItemsOffensiveTable.CONTENT_URI)
    adapter = new WikiItemsOffensiveAdapter(getActivity());
else if ...
...
else
    Log.e("Oh no", "The uri was not recognized. Adapter was not created");
```

Comment: are you saying it is possible to get any uri out of range possible uris?

Comment: @deadfish it all depends on how you call this fragment. With this log you can at least know that this is the case if you ever encounter the error again.

Comment: @deadfish perhaps you are receiving this error because your parent activity was re-created improperly and the fragment doesn't get the required arguments. It's hard to tell since you haven't supplied the activity's code and can't recreate the bug.

Comment: you were right about the problem in ifstatement. After your pointing what could be wrong I started testing if/else statements and the results were very strange. Comparing two the same texts not always was returning `true`. UriMatcher fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution but I didn't really fully understand what had happened.. I had to change if statements to UriMatcher. Somehow comparing uri with string uri didn't work always. Sometimes I was comparing `element1` with `element1` and it was saying, hey it is not the same! Very strange.